# Various Response Entity in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my controller I am having if condition and two different response type. I will get response in JSON format from "if" condition, but I am getting response from else condition like unexpected '0 , instead I need to get my error message'.

My controller code snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveuser", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody TestUser user)
            throws NotFoundException {

        System.out.println(user.getAnswer().size());
        if(questioncount == user.getAnswer().size())
        {
        return new ResponseEntity<TestUser>(service.addUser(user),
                HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            String one="one";

            String erromessage = "Only" + questioncount +" questions are allowed";
            System.out.println(erromessage);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(erromessage,HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: So, what is the actual response body you get, what would you like to get insted, and how are you reading it?

Comment: try `ResponseEntity<Object>`

Comment: As @JBNizet wrote, we really need to know more about how the reponse payload look, and what you're doing on the client side. But here's a theory: if the client tries to parse the payload as JSON even if the HTTP status code is an error code (406 in this case), then it might complain about the unexpected "O" character (which is the first character of your error response). "O" is not a valid first character for any kind of JSON.

Comment: I am using postman for consuming rest api. Here I need to get response from else block like "Only" + questioncount +" questions are allowed""